# Raster Reclassify fails upon Completion in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-10.0, spatial-analyst

When attempting to reclassify a raster in a student edition of ArcInfo 10, the program crashes without an error upon reaching 100%. The reclassified raster is written, but with no spatial info. I've got Spatial Analyst and the latest service pack. I suspected it might be a RAM issue, so I split the raster, but I'm having the same problem even with the much smaller dataset.

Edit: The plot thickens - I copied the file and mxd to a different location on the desktop, and now the reclassify works! Could having the original file located inside too many folders possibly have caused the problem?

Comment: I often have trouble using spatial analyst and geostatistical analyst with large dataseets working over the network.  Like with your experience, moving the data locally usually solves the problem.

Comment: Hmm, does ArcMap have a max filepath length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some agreement here that [Reclassify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000sr000000) is not the most efficient tool in ArcGIS.  A few alternatives, depending upon your needs, that may provide a more efficient approach, include:

**[InList](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z000000m7000000)**

> Determines which values from the first input are contained in a set of
>   other inputs, on a cell-by-cell basis

**[Con](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z00000005000000)**

> Performs a conditional if/else evaluation on each of the input cells
>   of an input raster.